# log color scale with spplot

Tags: r, gis, spatial, lattice, r-sp

How can I have a log color scale in spplot color key? I.e. so that in this map:
[image]

that instead of 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0 the numbers on the scale go like 0.0, 0.01 0.1 0.2 0.5 1.0 or something like this?

I tried the `do.log` argument, but it only works for SpatialPointsDataFrame (according to the docs). I also tried the scales argument:

```
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid)=~x+y
spplot(meuse.grid[,'dist'], scales=list(log="e"))
```

But it seems to be working only for the x and y coordinates, not the displayed variable and the color scale.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit convoluted, but this seems to do it:

```
library(sp)
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid)=~x+y
meuse.grid$ldist = log(meuse.grid$dist)
at = c(.05,.1,.2,.4,.8)
spplot(meuse.grid[,'ldist'], at = log(at), colorkey=list(labels = as.character(at)))
```

I would advice to not include 0 in the log scale!

Comment: Ha ha you' funny :-D Unless you're Chuck Norris, of course, then you can :) But this is the reason everyone uses `log(x + const)`, so that zero can be included. And then you start figuring which `const` to use and then it gets really messy :-D I used `sqrt` scale in one publication (maps of species' abundance). PS: your name is familiar to me, from some publications!